# Android Soft Keyboard not showing all `EditText`

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

First off all let me say that I've tried in the manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` and the result is the same.

I have a layout with an Header and a Footer and in between I have an `ScrollView`. Inside this, I have a `RelativeLayout` and inside this layout, I have one `EditText`  and a `LinearLayout` containing another `EditText` (this layout makes sense in my app).

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/placeholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I enter the activity and start entering text in the first edittext, the keyboard pops up, the scroll goes up a little so the I can see the text that I'm inserting. The problem is that the edittext is not all visible (I mean the bottom boundary). The keyboard stays just bellow the inserted text and not bellow the bottom of the edittext.

Now, since I already have the keyboard open, I scroll a bit so that I can see the top of the second edittext. When I touch the second edittext, it gains focus, and now, it automatically scrolls a bit not like the first edittext, that is, just enough to see the inserted text, but to the bottom of the edittext making the edittext all visible. This is what I want.

How can I make the behavior to be show always all the edittext?

Comment: check out the flags(that can help achieve ur requirements) available in the Editor Info class...That is u can set it as ime options for ur edittexts...

Comment: @DJphy Thanks but my ImeOptions are already set to next. I saw the options but I believe there is no flag to show all the edittext

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?